# ANDROID: How to fetch image URLs from user photos in facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am trying to get all user face book photo urls.
Currently I am able to get all image ids using Graph API. But I want get either image or image url to download. Following is the code snippet I am using..

```
  new GraphRequest(
                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                               // "/"+userId+"/albums",
                               "/"+userId+"/photos/uploaded",
                                null,
                                HttpMethod.GET,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                        System.out.println("photosResponse:"+response);  }
                                }
                        ).executeAsync();
```

sample response:

```
{
  Response: responseCode: 200,
  graphObject: {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2018-01-02T14:30:19+0000",
        "id": "12345678"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2017-12-30T11:44:26+0000",
        "id": "23456789"
      }]}}
```

and added these permissions

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_birthday", "user_posts", "user_photos");
```

I want get image urls, Help me.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/album 
 check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after going through the Graph API

Here is my code to get facebook image urls in all sizes

NOTE: We can add or remove parameters as per our requirement

```
    public void syncImagesToDB(String FBuserId) {
    if (FBuserId != null && FBuserId.length() > 0) {
        Bundle fb_params = new Bundle();
        fb_params.putString("fields", "id, name,created_time, link,images");
        final ArrayList<String> imageURL_list = new ArrayList<>();
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + FBuserId + "/photos/uploaded",
                fb_params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        System.out.println("photosResponse:" + response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                            Log.e("jsonObject ", " -> " + jsonObject);
                            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                            JSONArray jsonArray_data = jsonObject.optJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_data.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject album = null;
                                album = jsonArray_data.optJSONObject(i);
                                String id = album.optString("id");
                                String link = album.optString("link");
                                String created_time = album.optString("created_time");
                                JSONArray images_arr = album.optJSONArray("images");
                                if (images_arr.length() > 0) {
                                    JSONObject image_obj = images_arr.optJSONObject(0);
                                    String source_url = image_obj.optString("source");



                                    imageURL_list.add(source_url);

                                }
                                Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
                                params1.putString("fields", "id, name, link");
                            }
                            if (imageURL_list != null && imageURL_list.size() > 0) {


                            }

                            System.out.println("total uploaded images:" + imageURL_list.size());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

        ).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way to load image.

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID+ "/picture?type=large")
       .into(useimg);
```

Comment: sorry u can load album image from this url

Comment: try this and tell if any problem u face

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/ according to this graph api link 200 code show permission error

Comment: open link in browser like mozila with your id you get in response

Comment: i have added permissions, U can chk the qn now. and able to get image ids and album ids..  I am facing issue while getting url of those ids

Comment: have you load with any browser?because i try this url and getting images in browser

Comment: I tried that as well. I am using user photo id in the placed of userID.